# Using jQuery within AJAX-injected content

Tags: jquery, dialog

**tl;dr:** After loading content into the DOM, what is the earliest that jQuery has access to the added elements?

---

I am in the process of refactoring my existing JavaScript. Currently, I have modules that  load content into a dialog box and in the callback, after the dialog is loaded, take care of attaching events to the elements on the dialog.

I do not like that the module that loads the dialog knows the details of the loaded dialog elements. Instead, the approach I am now taking is that the module that loads the dialog simply does that an nothing more.

Now the responsibility of attaching the events falls on the dialog itself. The way I do this, is by embedding a JavaScript file within the markup of the content that gets loaded into the dialog and then calling an init method which does the binding of the events.

The problem I am facing right now is that for some reason, in the init method, jQuery does not find the elements the script is looking for. Almost like they have not yet been loaded into the DOM.

If, after the dialog loads, I manually look for the elements from the console, it works fine.

My questions is, when doing an AJAX call, at what point would jQuery have access to the newly added elements?

What do you think of my approach of embedding the JavaScript within the dialog markup? 
I can always have a callback that the module loading my dialog can use to initialize the events, but I am trying to encapsulate as much of the logic w/in the dialog so that the dialogs can be loaded from a number of places without having to repeat my initiating code.

Is there a better approach to attaching events, doing logic after the content is added to the DOM?

**Loading the dialog:**

```
loadMemberLoginHistoryDialog: function(memberId) {
    var dialogOptions = {
        onComplete: function(responseHtml) {}
    };
    var dialogUrl = '/members/' + memberId + '/loginHistoryDialog';
    $.favsDialog(dialogUrl, dialogOptions);
}
```

**Script in the markup of the content that is loaded in the dialog:**

```
        <script src="/js/zMemberLoginHistoryDialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            favsManageMemberLoginHistoryDialog.init('@Constants.LanguageCode');
        </script>
```

**favsManageMemberLoginHistoryDialog module:**

```
var favsManageMemberLoginHistoryDialog = function() {
   function initializeControls() {
        $(".frmManageMembersMemberDelete")
            .submit(function() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    return {
        init: function(language) {
            languageCode = language;
            initializeControls();
        }
    }; //return
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some code as an example of what exactly you're doing?

Comment: I've added a code sample

Comment: Try looking into this: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: _"when doing an AJAX call, at what point would jQuery have access to the newly added elements?"_ - jQuery (and, more broadly, JavaScript) has access immediately once the elements are actually added. _But,_ if it's an Ajax call which is _asynchronous_ doing the adding then the elements won't be there until the call completes so you should only try to access such elements from the success/complete callback of the Ajax request.